# Efficiently creating a class inside a class method and passing it out of there?

Tags: c++, return-value-optimization

```
    CList<CString> Split(char delim) {
        CList<CString> subStrings;
        for (char* ps = Buffer(); *ps; ps++) {
            char* pe;
            for (pe = ps; *pe && (*pe != delim); pe++)
                ;
            subStrings.Append (CString(ps, int (pe - ps)));
            if (!*pe)
                break;
            ps = pe;
        }
        return subStrings;
    }

    CList<CString> values = s.Split(';');
```

The final statement causes the list's copy constructor to be called two times: First time when subString gets passed out of the method. The instance on the stack local to Split() gets copied (to only the compiler knows where) to persist long enough to be copied again to "values".

How would I go about not having two (rather expensive) list copy operations here without fundamentally changing my code (like e.g. adding a CList& parameter to Split())?

Edit:

Compiler flags are set to use c++20.

Edit 2:

Small test project.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1GVRJ9lbu2nYnhsLLv3YbCjtKr8m6-k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What compiler do you use? The copy on return was removed in C++11 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). Instead of CString and CList use std::string and std::vector with emplace_back.

Comment: VS 2019 community ed. (debug code). I can see in the debugger that the list gets copied twice.

Comment: IIRC return value optimization became mandatory with C++17. Maybe the compiler settings are set to C++11 (copy elision possible but not mandatory).

Comment: Are you sure this is a copy ctor, not move ctor?

Comment: Hmm, this is weird. I tried to build a [mre] using a custom CList class displaying the ctor/dtor usage, and when using the MSVC tool chain one single copy ctor is used (no copy ctor is ever used with the CLang tool chain). I am using MSVC2019 community version 16.10.4 . Said differently **please provide a [mre]**...

Comment: Hi Serge, I added a link to my Google Drive with a 7z archive containing a small test project (source files, test code, VS sln + vcproj).

Comment: @Eugene: The class' copy function gets called, which I have written.

Comment: So CList s your own class,  not the one from MFC?

Comment: Looks like debug builds will still generate code with extra copies. (At least visual studio 2019 does)

Comment: @Eugene: Yes, it is my code.

Comment: The question was: Are you the implementer of `CList` and `CString`, or are you using those types from elsewhere (such as MFC)? The question was not: Did you write this code?

Comment: Do not use this naming convention for your own classes. Classes with exactly the same names exist in MFC, which is an old GUI library from Visual Studio.

Comment: @IInspectable: Let me ask you something: When I wrote the code of CList, then who is its implementer? When I am the implementer, am I using the code from somewhere else?

Comment: You have just confused everybody. We were thinking you were referring to MFC classes.

Comment: @PKramer _Looks like debug builds will still generate code with extra copies. (At least visual studio 2019 does)_ This is exactly what I noticed a few weeks ago while commenting to an answer of yet another question. (In release mode, it works as expected.)

Comment: _When I wrote the code of CList, then who is its implementer?_ Unfortunately, all the cool names already seem to be occupied. The last resort is to put it into your own namespace. I managed to establish this even for naming of some of our products (i.e. in marketing)...

Comment: It's just for a small C++ exercise, so what.

Comment: @Eugene: It appears the only one confused here was you. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I ran some tests with this code (using visual studio 2019), and I observe differences in behavior in debug and release builds. The debug builds DO call copy constructors and don't do RVO/copy elision. Release builds do the optimization and no unecessary copying is done. This example shows you how to split strings with minimal copying (in release builds)

This result did surprise me somewhat, so thanks for asking this question. I did learn something to today :)

The output of the release build is as expected (emplace_back doesn't copy either):

```
-----------------------------------------------------
calling split function

my_list::my_list
  my_string::my_string
  my_string::my_string
  my_string::my_string
  my_string::my_string
-----------------------------------------------------
result of split

the
quick
brown
fox

-----------------------------------------------------
cleanup vector starting
my_list::~my_list
  my_string::~my_string
  my_string::~my_string
  my_string::~my_string
  my_string::~my_string
```

However the debug build clearly doesn't do that kind of optimization :

```
my_list::my_list
  my_string::my_string
  my_string::my_string
  my_string::my_string
  my_string::my_string
  my_string::my_string(const my_string&), copy constructor
  my_string::my_string(const my_string&), copy constructor
  my_string::my_string(const my_string&), copy constructor
  my_string::my_string(const my_string&), copy constructor
my_list::my_list(const my_list&), copy constructor
my_list::~my_list
  my_string::~my_string
  my_string::~my_string
  my_string::~my_string
  my_string::~my_string
-----------------------------------------------------
result of split

the
quick
brown
fox

-----------------------------------------------------
cleanup vector starting
my_list::~my_list
  my_string::~my_string
  my_string::~my_string
  my_string::~my_string
  my_string::~my_string
```

This is the test code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct my_string
{
    my_string(const char* from, const char* to) :
        value(from, to)
    {
        std::cout << "  my_string::my_string\n";
    }

    my_string(const my_string& rhs) :
        value{ rhs.value }
    {
        std::cout << "  my_string::my_string(const my_string&), copy constructor\n";
    }

    my_string(my_string&& rhs) :
        value{ std::move(rhs.value) }
    {
        std::cout << "  my_string::my_string(my_string&&), move constructor\n";
    }


    ~my_string()
    {
        std::cout << "  my_string::~my_string\n";
    }
 
    std::string value;
};


struct my_list
{
    my_list()
    {
        // note reserving some more room up front will reduce reallocations 
        // try commenting this out and you will see many more strings created/destroyed
        // because of vector reallocation
        strings.reserve(128);
        std::cout << "my_list::my_list\n";
    }

    my_list(const my_list& rhs) :
        strings{ rhs.strings }
    {
        std::cout << "my_list::my_list(const my_list&), copy constructor\n";
    }

    ~my_list()
    {
        std::cout << "my_list::~my_list\n";
    }

    std::vector<my_string> strings;
};


my_list split(const char* string, char delim)
{
    my_list list;

    for (const char* ps = string; *ps != 0; ++ps)
    {
        const char* pe{ ps };
        while ((*pe != 0) && (*pe != delim)) 
        {
            ++pe;
        }
    
        list.strings.emplace_back(ps,pe);
        ps = pe;
    }

    return list;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "-----------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "calling spit function\n\n";

    {
        auto mylist = split("the,quick,brown,fox", ',');

        std::cout << "-----------------------------------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "result of split \n\n";

        for (const auto& mystring : mylist.strings)
        {
            std::cout << mystring.value << "\n";
        }

        std::cout << "\n-----------------------------------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "cleanup vector starting";
    }
}
```